# I want to convert multiple columns into rows but along with it's corresponding data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

Currently my dataframe looks like this,

[image]

And I want something like this,

```
  Filename    Data_Extracted
  file1        data of file1
  file2        data of file2
```

Currently File1 & File2 are actually the columns of the dataframe and data of file1 & file 2 are the records

is there any way to do that?

Comment: I think you'll want to add more debugging details or include your code as text instead of an image if you want to avoid getting your question closed

Comment: Sure, will keep it mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dictionary has the structure `{filename1: data1, filename2: data2, ...}`, then you can do something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=filename_dict.items(), columns=['Filename', 'Data_Extracted'])
```